# How do I send log to syslog in python?

Tags: python, syslog

I have a script to process a file. At the beginning I would like to check if the file exist, if exist and not empty or not too old. If satisfied continue processing. If not satisfied, how do I log to syslog and exit without continue?
Here's my code:

```
import sys
import os
import time

if os.path.isfile("/path/file"):
    x=os.stat('/path/file')
    Result=(time.time()-x.st_mtime)
    if os.stat("/path/file").st_size != 0 && Result > 300:
        f = open("/path/file", "r")
    else:
        ## log to syslog then exit script
else:
    ## log to syslog thn exit script

## section to continue processing
f1_to_process = f.read()
...
f.close()
```

Read a few doc on logging, not quite understand the right way to implement it. I am not sure if my logic makes any sense. Could I have some advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually, a process that's intended to log to system logs will be run as a service, and the program that's responsible for launching it (systemd, in modern Linux systems) is responsible for routing its stdout and stderr to the appropriate logs. It should be rare that you ever write code to route logs as part of your program itself -- let the sysadmin _installing_ your program decide where to direct its output; they're the person who knows best what their corporate standard for log management is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`syslog`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/syslog.html) module along with the `quit` function:

```py
import sys
import os
import time
from syslog import syslog

def log_and_exit(message):
    syslog(message)
    quit()

if os.path.isfile("/path/file"):
    x=os.stat('/path/file')
    Result=(time.time()-x.st_mtime)
    if os.stat("/path/file").st_size != 0 && Result > 300:
        f = open("/path/file", "r")
    else:
        log_and_exit("foo")
else:
    log_and_exit("bar")

## section to continue processing
f1_to_process = f.read()
# ...
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Aplet123, it works great! I need to work on other lines, replaced "&&" with "and".